# null element id for DataGrid ButtonColumns

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a bit of JavaScript in one of my pages that avoids the problem of users double-clicking buttons on a form and causing double submissions during asynchronous postbacks:

`var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);`

```
var btn;

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
  document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
  var btnId = args._postBackElement.id;
  btn = document.getElementById(btnId);
  if (btn != null && (btn.type == "button" || btn.type == "submit"))
    btn.disabled = true;
}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
  document.body.style.cursor = "default";
  if (btn != null) btn.disabled = false;
}
```

This isn't working with DataGrid ButtonColumns.  document.getElementById(btnId) returns null for those.

If I use a TemplateColumn and put a Button control inside, that works fine.

Looking at the HTML that gets rendered for the DataGrid, I can see that ASP.NET isn't outputting an onclick for the ButtonColumn, where it does do so for a Button inside a TemplateColumn:

**ButtonColumn:**

```
<input type="submit"
  name="ctl00$placeholderContent$dgCommittees$ctl03$ctl00"
  value="Edit" />
```

**Button in TemplateColumn:**

```
<input type="submit"
  name="ctl00$placeholderContent$dgCommittees$ctl03$cmdDelete"
  value="Delete"
  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this committee?');
    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
     new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$placeholderContent$dgCommittees$ctl03$cmdDelete", "", true, "", "", false, false))"
  id="ctl00_placeholderContent_dgCommittees_ctl03_cmdDelete" />
```

Obviously the answer to "how do I make this work?" is to simply replace all my ButtonColumns with Buttons in TemplateColumns.

I'm curious if anyone knows *why* ASP.NET renders ButtonColumns this way though, and if there's some way to get it to render them the same as Buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS has a standard implementation of bound fields, which does not set ID or attributes for ButtonColumn created buttons.

To be a bit more specific, whenever a grid creates cells and sub-sequentially buttons, it calls InitializeCell:

```
public override void InitializeCell(TableCell cell, int columnIndex, ListItemType itemType)
{
    base.InitializeCell(cell, columnIndex, itemType);
    if ((itemType != ListItemType.Header) && (itemType != ListItemType.Footer))
    {
        WebControl child = null;
        if (this.ButtonType == ButtonColumnType.LinkButton)
            ...
        else
        {
            child = new Button {
                Text = this.Text,
                CommandName = this.CommandName,
                CausesValidation = this.CausesValidation,
                ValidationGroup = this.ValidationGroup
            };
        }
        ...
        cell.Controls.Add(child);
    }
}
```

As you can see, that's all there is to a button.

If you want it to have IDs and "onclick" attributes, you could use something like this:

```
protected void grid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //assuming that a first cell is a ButtonField
        //note that in edit mode a button may be at some other index that 0
        Button btn = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {
            btn.OnClientClick = "return confirm('are you sure?')";
            btn.ID = "myButtonX";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to add event handlers on your buttons. Here is a sample:

```
function onclick () {
  alert("1");
}
$(function () {
  $("input[type='submit']").click(onclick);
});
```

This code will attach the `onclick` function to the `onclick` event for all `input` elements of type `submit` when the DOM is ready.

The [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) technique may interest you.

I would like to mention that Microsoft supports JQuery, and they will make support for it in upcoming versions of Visual Studio. For more information please visit http://live.visitmix.com/.